# Keep whitespaces when auto-formatting Java code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting

I have a small issue with IntelliJ not making my code more readable through auto-formatting, but more confusing.

Hence the following code excerpt:

```
private static float _triangleCoords[] = {
     0.0f,  0.62f, 0f,
    -0.5f, -0.31f, 0f,
     0.5f, -0.31f, 0f
};
```

If I run Java auto-formatting, IntelliJ formats it like this:

```
private static float _triangleCoords[] = {
    0.0f, 0.62f, 0f,
    -0.5f, -0.31f, 0f,
    0.5f, -0.31f, 0f
};
```

I don't want it to strip away the spaces since they align the floats nicely. I also don't want to write `+` signs in front of positive floats just to keep it that way.

How can I turn this formatting off?

Comment: I don't think you can turn it off. It annoys me too.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable reformatting for blocks of codes with comments, eg

```
private static float _triangleCoords[] = {
        // @formatter:off
        0.0f,   0.62f, 0f,
        -0.5f, -0.31f, 0f,
        0.5f,  -0.31f, 0f
        // @formatter:on
};
```

Go to Preferences -> Code Style -> General -> Formatter Control to enable format control with comments. You can also define a macro/template to surround a block of code with formatter comments to make life a bit easier.

Comment: It does, but other than putting up with the Intellij formatting or not auto formatting, it's your only choice.

Comment: Upvoted, but I still wait for an answer for trying to fix this without the formatter comments ;O